# Duda npm y Angular

Tags: angular, npm

Soy nuevo en Angular y tenía una duda pero no encuentro la respuesta.

Estoy acostumbrado a trabajar con *node* y a usar la multitud de paquetes NPM existentes. Al empezar a trabajar con *Angular* y como éste usa en sí paquetes NPM como `'@angular/core'`,etc; me preguntaba si podría usar todos los paquetes de [npmjs](http://npmjs.com/) en mi proyecto o no tiene nada que ver.

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, puedes usar casi todo el set de paquetes disponibles en NPM.

Tanto lo que instales con `npm` como con `yarn` esos paquetes están identificados en un archivo `package.json`, que esta en el root de tu proyecto.

El `package.json` está organizado en dos grupos de paquetes:

- Las *Dependencies*  son esenciales para ejecutar aplicaciones.
- Las *DevDependencies* solo son necesarias para desarrollar aplicaciones.

---

Para instalar paquetes como 'Dependecies', debes ejecutar:

```
npm install <package-name> --save 
yarn add <package-name>
```

Para instalar paquetes como 'DevDependencies', debes ejecutar:

```
npm install <package-name> --save-dev 
yarn add <package-name> --dev
```